# Problem using File Append in Log4j 2 with runtime variable substitutions

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have an XML logging configuration where I have a simple console and rolling logging for my app, but I also want to produce separate files for certain activities.  Here is the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" packages="com.package1">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="server.log.dir">/opt/tomcat/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <ThresholdFilter level="debug"/>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X{account} %c - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="rolling" fileName="${server.log.dir}/app.log" filePattern="${server.log.dir}/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json">
                <EventTemplateAdditionalField key="account" format="JSON" value='{"$resolver": "mdc", "key": "account" }'/>
                <EventTemplateAdditionalField key="pipeline" format="JSON" value='{"$resolver": "mdc", "key": "pipeline" }'/>
            </JsonTemplateLayout>
        </RollingFile>
        <Routing name="batchLogging">
            <!-- here is the dynamic log file for each activity -->
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:activity}">
                <Route key="batch">
                    <File name="batchLogger"
                                 filename="${server.log.dir}/$${ctx:batch_log}"
                                 append="false">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %X{account} %X{pipeline} [%t] %c - %m%n"/>
                        <DynamicThresholdFilter key="batch_level" defaultTreshold="debug" onMatch="ACCEPT">
                            <KeyValuePair key="fatal" value="FATAL"/>
                            <KeyValuePair key="error" value="ERROR"/>
                            <KeyValuePair key="warn" value="WARN"/>
                            <KeyValuePair key="info" value="INFO"/>
                            <KeyValuePair key="debug" value="DEBUG"/>
                        </DynamicThresholdFilter>
                    </File>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn"/>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple" level="debug"/>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter" level="debug"/>
        <Logger name="com.amazonaws" level="warn"/>
        <Logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="warn"/>
        <Logger name="org.apache.hadoop" level="warn"/>
        <Logger name="org.apache.solr" level="warn" additivity="false"/>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="warn"/>
        <Logger name="ro.isdc" level="info"/>
        <Logger name="org.xhtmlrenderer" level="info"/>

        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rolling"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="batchLogging"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In my code I have the following:

```
public BatchResult call() throws Exception {
    String batchFilename = batch.getAccountId().val() + "/batches/" + batch.getId() + "/" + batch.getLogFilename();
    try {
         ThreadContext.put("activity", "batch");
         ThreadContext.put("batch_log", batchFilename );
         ThreadContext.put("batch_level", options.containsKey("logLevel") ? (String)options.get("logLevel") : Level.DEBUG.name() );
         return importData(currentUser, filename, scriptName, batch, sendEmail, triggerBuilders, options);
    } finally {
         ThreadContext.remove("batch_log");
         ThreadContext.remove("batch_level");
         ThreadContext.remove("activity");
         File logDir = new File(etlEnvironment.getServerDataHome(), "archive");
         uploadLogs(new File( logDir, batchFilename), batch);
    }
}
```

But I get this error over and over in the logs:

```
ERROR StatusConsoleListener Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@551f811a] unable to create manager for [/opt/tomcat/logs/archive/${ctx:batch_log}] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@203052b9]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@551f811a] unable to create manager for [/opt/tomcat/logs/archive/${ctx:batch_log}] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@203052b9]
```

And you can see it substituted the ${server.log.dir} in the path, but it failed to substitute the ${ctx:batch_log} statement.  I'm using the $$ syntax to delay substitution until the runtime, but the error shows the file appender doesn't seem to either see the variable, or resolve the 2nd `${}`.  I don't have a lot more details in the status logger in log4j to know why it's not working.  So does File appender not support doing this?  From the docs it definitely seems like it would.

Side burn: Chatgpt just lead me in a circle of every more complex and incorrect hallucinations.  AI has consistently let me down whenever I try to "program" with it.  And why is everyone so convinced AI is going to replace us?!

The goal is to produce a single log file for each time that code runs, and collect all log events that occur on the thread that executes that job.  One issue I'm not sure how log4j is going to know to close the file when the job finishes, but I'll fix that once it actually just creates the file.  So what am I missing in how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Route>` element is special: it is one of the few plugins that defers the initialization of children (cf. [Javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/routing/Route.html)).

The XML inside of `<Route>` is evaluated at runtime, when the route is chosen for the **first** time. Therefore you should use `${ctx:batch_log}` instead of `$${ctx:batch_log}`, because technically this is not a delayed evaluation (the `fileName` parameter does not accept those).

You might also want to change the key of your route: appenders are initialized only once per key, so the file appender will only retain the first value of `${ctx:batch_log}`. In order to have a different appender per value of `${ctx:batch_log}`, use `${ctx:batch_log}` as key and make your only `<Route>` the default one by removing the `key` attribute.

```xml
<!-- This is evaluated at configuration time, so we need `$$` to delay it -->
<Routes pattern="$${ctx:batch_log}">
    <!-- Default route, matches any key -->
    <Route>
        <!-- This part is evaluated when the route is chosen, so no `$$` -->
        <!-- The name must be unique -->
        <File name="batchLogger-${ctx:batch_log}"
              filename="${server.log.dir}/${ctx:batch_log}"
              append="false">
        ...
        </File>
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz you nailed it!  One question I have with this is how are the files closed when a job is finished?  I looked at the IdlePurgePolicy to do this, but I wasn't sure if that would close the log files, or remove the appender and never work again after the purge period?

Comment: The `IdlePurgePolicy` closes unused appenders (which means also their files). After the appender is closed an appender with the same file can be reopened if necessary.